# Win32 API call through a serivce

Tags: c#, winapi

I have develop a program which turns off the monitor by standard sendmassage api call:

```
    public int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    public int SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170;
    const int HWND_BROADCAST  = 0xFFFF;
    SendMessage(-1, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);
```

My question is I dont want it to be a windows form, but a windows service instead... The sendmessage doesnt not in a windows service. How can I get it to work?

Regards,
Christian

Comment: The sendmessage command does not _________ in a windows service?  You missed a word.

Comment: sorry.... :) The sendmessage-command doesnt work in my windows service.

Answer (score 1):

Using `HWND_BROADCAST` / -1 is so wrong I don't even know where to begin, see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/06/13/629451.aspx) for details

If for whatever reason you can't create a window, you could try to PInvoke the DefWindowProc function directly

Are you even sure it is possible to do this from a service? You might have to call CreateProcessAsUser and start a helper app

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetDesktopWindow method and send the message to that window. Or you can use FindWindow and FindWindowEx methods to get the currently active window and send message there. Or you can add a reference to System.Windows.Forms in your service and instantiate a Form object and use that handle to send the message.

Comment: I already tried the last solution, adding a form, but with no result:

    Form f = new Form();
    SendMessage(f.Handle.ToInt32(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);

Comment: SendMessage(GetDesktopWindow().ToInt32(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2); Doesnt work either.....

Comment: 1. Last method is not a best practice (Adding form reference).
2. GetDesktopWindow: Might have some thing to do with the security permission in your system.

Try using FindWindow. If that doesn't works either, I am clueless then.